# Argument as to why a word does not belong to a language (pumping lemma)

Tags: formal-languages, pumping-lemma

Given the language $D = \{x^n y^n y^m \mid n,m \geq 0\}$, I have applied the pumping lemma with $k>0$, $n=k$ and $m=0$ and found a word $z = x^{k+q} y^k$ with $q>0$ that does not belong to $D$.

However, it is not sufficient to argue that the number of $x$'s and $y$'s is not equal and thus the word does not belong to $D$, as $D$ does not need an equal number of $x$'s and $y$'s.

So how would one instead argue that $z$ does not belong to $D$?

Comment: The word $x^{k+q} y^k$ is not in your language for any $k$ and any $q > 0$. So I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the argument as to why your statement is true, is it that the number of $x$'s must be $\leq$ the number of $y$'s for a word to belong in the language $D$?

Comment: Right, that’s precisely the definition of $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to write your language is $\{x^n y^m \mid n \leq m\}$. You can see this by proving that every word in $D$ belongs to this set, and vice versa (details left to you).

This shows that if $q > 0$, then $x^{k+q} y^k \notin D$.